# Need to link to index.html

Tags: html, hugo, hugo-shortcode

I try to create a bunch of local HTML files that should serve as a documentation for some software. No webserver should be involved, just HTML files viewed by a webbrowser. I use hugo to create the pages, but I have problems linking to the main page (index.html).

My `config.toml` is this:

```
#baseURL = "http://example.com"
languageCode = "en-us"
title = "foo"
theme = "mytheme"

relativeURLs = true
canonifyURLs = false
uglyURLs = true
```

and my main page is `_index.md` in the root folder.

How do I create a shortcode or whatever that creates a relative link to the `index.html` in the root folder (`content` folder in hugo). The `index.html` page gets created, but I have not succeeded to create a link to that page. Of course I could hard code the link, but this is not what I want.

The sample repository is at https://github.com/pgundlach/hugoexample/ .

I have tried a shortcode with a definition like `{{ with .Site.GetPage "section" "_index.md"  }}{{ .Relpermalink }}{{ end}}` but this didn't work.

Disclosure: This is actually a question I have tried on https://discourse.gohugo.io/ but without any luck. So the question might be "stupid" or I am missing something obvious.

Answer (score 1):

I am also a beginner. However, I think that the index.md file should be in your content directory. Then you should create an index.html file in your layouts directory for rendering the .md file.

Or am I missing what you are trying to do here?

Docs about the directory structure: https://gohugo.io/getting-started/directory-structure/

Comment: In the hugo docs regarding `index`, it is `_index.md` and not `index.md`. I want to have a url like `timo.com/index.html`, however, after page rendering `index.html` disappears. I want it to remain.

Comment: Use `uglyurls = true` in the config file.